# How to pass dynamically string for print statement, TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Tags: python

**First case:**

- str_ = `'There is only %s'` and `values = [1]`
- Expected out is: `'There is only 1'`

**Second case:**

- str_ = `'There are two %s and %s'` and `values = [1, 2]`
- Expected out is   `'There are two 1 and 2'`

**I also tried to pass tuple of values:**

```
print(str_  %(values))
```

But I got type error `TypeError: not enough arguments for format string`

Comment: If you make `values` a tuple instead of a list, it works. If necessary you can convert an existing list to a tuple with the `tuple` constructor: `str_ % tuple(values)`.

Comment: I would recommand you read up on how to do string formatting, [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) is a link ot the docs, its not complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If *format* requires a single argument, *values* may be a single non-tuple object. Otherwise, *values* must be a tuple with exactly the number of items specified by the *format* string, or a single mapping object (for example, a dictionary).
>
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting

So, make sure `values` is a tuple. If you have an existing list which you need to work with, turn it into a tuple before using it with `%`:

```
str_ % tuple(values)
```

---

`(values)` does *not* convert to a tuple; it's just surrounding the value with grouping parentheses which do nothing. It's the comma that makes the tuple, not the parentheses:

```
(values,)
```

However, this would be a tuple with one element, a list. That's also not what you want. You need the `tuple` constructor to turn a list into a tuple, or unpack an iterable into a tuple literal:

```
(*values,)
```